# Homotopy equivalence of one-point space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

[image]

e) Let $f: \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \{0\}$. Then $g \circ f = id_{\{0\}}$ since $f$ is the inclusion map. But $f \circ g=f(x)\ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. How do I show $g$ is homotopic to $id_{\mathbb{R}^n}$?

f) Any hints on how to start here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (e), if I understand correctly, you have defined $f:\{0\}\to\mathbb R^n$ by $f(0)=0$, and $g:\mathbb R^n\to\{0\}$ by $g(x)=0$ (the only possible function). Thus, $g\circ f(0)=g(0)=0$, which is the identity function on $\{0\}$. Furthermore, $f\circ g(x)=f(0)=0$. We need to construct a homotopy $H:\mathbb R^n\times I\to\mathbb R^n$ such that $H(x,0)=0$ and $H(x,1)=x$. For this, we might try the straight-line homotopy $H(x,t)=tx$. Can you see why this works?

For (f), note that there are only two possible functions from $\{0\}$ to $\{0,1\}$. Call them $f_0$ and $f_1$, where $f_0(0)=0$ and $f_1(0)=1$. Let $g:\{0,1\}\to \{0\}$ be given by $g(x)=0$. Clearly whether $i=0$ or $i=1$, $g\circ f_i(0)=g(i)=0$, which is the identity function on $\{0\}$. But $f_1\circ g(x)=f_1(0)=1$. We need a homotopy $H:\{0,1\}\times I\to\{0,1\}$ such that $H(x,0)=1$ and $H(x,1)=x$. In particular, $H(0,t)$ is a continuous function from $1$ to $0$. Can you prove that this means that $H(0,t)$ must be discontinuous? The argument for $f_0$ is symmetric.

Comment: For e) You showed $f \circ g$ is homotopic to the identity of $\mathbb{R}^n$ right? And concluded 0 is homotopic to $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: It is not quite right to say that one point is homotopic to the other. When saying that two things are homotopic, those things are usually functions. Rather, we showed that the constant function and the identity function on $\mathbb R^n$ are homotopic, and that homotopy "moves" continuously between the function that maps $x$ to $0$ and the function that maps $x$ to $x$.